# Unmangling the result of std::type_info::name

Tags: c++, gcc, name-mangling

I'm currently working on some logging code that supposed to - among other things - print information about the calling function. This should be relatively easy, standard C++ has a `type_info` class. This contains the name of the typeid'd class/function/etc. but it's mangled. It's not very useful. I.e. `typeid(std::vector<int>).name()` returns `St6vectorIiSaIiEE`.

Is there a way to produce something useful from this? Like `std::vector<int>` for the above example. If it only works for non-template classes, that's fine too.

The solution should work for gcc, but it would be better if I could port it. It's for logging so it's not so important that it can't be turned off, but it should be helpful for debugging.

Answer (score 147, accepted):

Given the attention this question / answer receives, and the valuable feedback from [GManNickG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/281818/unmangling-the-result-of-stdtype-infoname/4541470#comment26629807_4541470), I have cleaned up the code a little bit. Two versions are given: one with C++11 features and another one with only C++98 features.

In file **type.hpp**

```cpp
#ifndef TYPE_HPP
#define TYPE_HPP

#include <string>
#include <typeinfo>

std::string demangle(const char* name);

template <class T>
std::string type(const T& t) {

    return demangle(typeid(t).name());
}

#endif
```

In file **type.cpp** (requires C++11)

```cpp
#include "type.hpp"
#ifdef __GNUG__
#include <cstdlib>
#include <memory>
#include <cxxabi.h>

std::string demangle(const char* name) {

    int status = -4; // some arbitrary value to eliminate the compiler warning

    // enable c++11 by passing the flag -std=c++11 to g++
    std::unique_ptr<char, void(*)(void*)> res {
        abi::__cxa_demangle(name, NULL, NULL, &status),
        std::free
    };

    return (status==0) ? res.get() : name ;
}

#else

// does nothing if not g++
std::string demangle(const char* name) {
    return name;
}

#endif
```

Usage:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "type.hpp"

struct Base { virtual ~Base() {} };

struct Derived : public Base { };

int main() {

    Base* ptr_base = new Derived(); // Please use smart pointers in YOUR code!

    std::cout << "Type of ptr_base: " << type(ptr_base) << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Type of pointee: " << type(*ptr_base) << std::endl;

    delete ptr_base;
}
```

It prints:

Type of ptr_base: `Base*`
Type of pointee: `Derived`

Tested with g++ 4.7.2, g++ 4.9.0 20140302 (experimental), clang++ 3.4 (trunk 184647), clang 3.5 (trunk 202594) on Linux 64 bit and g++ 4.7.2 (Mingw32, Win32 XP SP2).

If you cannot use C++11 features, here is how it can be done in C++98, the file **type.cpp** is now:

```cpp
#include "type.hpp"
#ifdef __GNUG__
#include <cstdlib>
#include <memory>
#include <cxxabi.h>

struct handle {
    char* p;
    handle(char* ptr) : p(ptr) { }
    ~handle() { std::free(p); }
};

std::string demangle(const char* name) {

    int status = -4; // some arbitrary value to eliminate the compiler warning

    handle result( abi::__cxa_demangle(name, NULL, NULL, &status) );

    return (status==0) ? result.p : name ;
}

#else

// does nothing if not g++
std::string demangle(const char* name) {
    return name;
}

#endif
```

---

---

*(Update from Sep 8, 2013)*

[The accepted answer (as of Sep 7, 2013)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/281876/341970), when the call to `abi::__cxa_demangle()` is successful, **returns a pointer to a local, stack allocated array**... ouch!
Also note that if you provide a buffer, `abi::__cxa_demangle()` assumes it to be allocated on the heap. Allocating the buffer on the stack is a bug (from the gnu doc): *"If `output_buffer` is not long enough, it is expanded using `realloc`."* **Calling `realloc()` on a pointer to the stack**... ouch! (See also [Igor Skochinsky](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/281818/unmangling-the-result-of-stdtype-infoname#comment16312718_4541470)'s  kind comment.)

You can easily verify both of these bugs: just reduce the buffer size in the accepted answer (as of Sep 7, 2013)  from 1024 to something smaller, for example 16, and give it something with a name *not* longer than 15 (so `realloc()` is *not* called). Still, depending on your system and the compiler optimizations, the output will be: garbage / nothing / program crash.
To verify the second bug: set the buffer size to 1 and call it with something whose name is longer than 1 character. When you run it, the program almost assuredly crashes as it attempts to call `realloc()` with a pointer to the stack.

---

*(The old answer from Dec 27, 2010)*

Important changes made to [KeithB's code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/281876/341970): **the buffer has to be either allocated by malloc or specified as NULL.** Do NOT allocate it on the stack.

It's wise to check that status as well.

I failed to find `HAVE_CXA_DEMANGLE`. I check `__GNUG__` although that does not guarantee that the code will even compile. Anyone has a better idea?

```cpp
#include <cxxabi.h>

const string demangle(const char* name) {

    int status = -4;

    char* res = abi::__cxa_demangle(name, NULL, NULL, &status);

    const char* const demangled_name = (status==0)?res:name;

    string ret_val(demangled_name);

    free(res);

    return ret_val;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain why the buffer cannot be allocated on the stack? Because so far it worked fine for me.

Comment: Last time I checked `abi::__cxa_demangle` expected it to be allocated on the stack. I guess it calls `realloc` if the buffer is not large enough. So if your buffer on the stack happens to be sufficiently large then it won't call realloc and this bug remains unnoticed. It is still a bug.

Comment: From the [docs](http://idlebox.net/2008/0901-stacktrace-demangled/cxa_demangle.htt): `output_buffer` A region of memory, allocated with malloc, of *length bytes, into which the demangled name is stored. If output_buffer is not long enough, it is expanded using realloc. output_buffer may instead be NULL; in that case, the demangled name is placed in a region of memory allocated with malloc.

Comment: @IgorSkochinsky Yes, there is a typo in my previous comment but I cannot edit that. What I wanted to write: "Last time I checked `abi::__cxa_demangle` expected it to be allocated **on the heap.**" Thank you very much for looking up the doc!

Comment: Note that technically this can leak if `ret_val` throws during construction. You can use a scope guard to guard against that.

Comment: @GManNickG Would you be so kind to check my updated answer? I hope the code is now bug free. Many thanks!

Comment: @terminus I am glad you find it helpful. :)

Comment: If would probably be more clear to use `std::unique_ptr<char, decltype(&std::free)>` as the signature for your pointer.

Comment: @mindvirus Yes, thanks, I saw your earlier edit request. However, I am not in favor of this change: I have had a very weird compile error when passing `&tolower` (`::tolower` vs. `std::tolower`) in a similar situation. This was most likely a compiler quirk but unless you can *guarantee that all compilers* handle `decltype(&std::free)` properly in all cases, I leave it the way it is; the version in the answer will work.

Comment: Even incorrect compilers :)? Anyway, this was the pattern that cplusplus.com documents suggest: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/unique_ptr/~unique_ptr/

Comment: @mindvirus Don't get me wrong: In theory, it should be done the way you suggest, you are absolutely right. Unfortunately, in practice, many people are stuck with an older (quirky) compiler. Nobody has ever complained about the current solution not compiling; and at the moment I don't have time to verify whether your suggested change works correctly on older versions of gcc / clang (yes, even if they are somewhat broken). Sorry...

Comment: Heh, no worries, just saw it passing by, turned out it was a waaay deeper rabbit hole than I expected.

Comment: Wait, isn't the memory malloc'ed by __cxa_demangle going to get free'ed as it is returned as res.get()? That's not going to work when someone tries to use that returned pointer since it's already been free'ed. You'd need to strdup the res.get() and the caller of the function will have to call free themselves no? EDIT: nvm, I didn't see it was being returned as a std::string.

Comment: @Ali I tested the last snippet in your post and works fine. Just a point about it. Since some people doesn't include the namespace std, to avoid compilation errors it would be nice if you could replace `string` with `std::string`. Thank-you

Comment: @julianromera Thanks for the feedback. However, I don't see any unqualified `string` in the *proposed solution*: It uses `std::string` everywhere. I only see a single `string` in the original post from 2010, which is certainly not the solution that I would recommend. Where do you see `string` in the proposed solution?

Comment: @Ali Oh I must have missed that, now I see that you are right.

Comment: ``HAVE_CXA_DEMANGLE`` is something your configure scripts would test for and then set either on the compiler command line or in a ``config.h`` file.

Answer (score 40):

Boost core contains a demangler. Checkout [core/demangle.hpp](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/libs/core/doc/html/core/demangle.html#core.demangle.header_boost_core_demangle_hpp):

```
#include <boost/core/demangle.hpp>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <iostream>

template<class T> struct X
{
};

int main()
{
    char const * name = typeid( X<int> ).name();

    std::cout << name << std::endl; // prints 1XIiE
    std::cout << boost::core::demangle( name ) << std::endl; // prints X<int>
}
```

It's basically just a wrapper for `abi::__cxa_demangle`, as has been suggested previously.

Comment: If boost is an option, this is the best way to go!

Answer (score 20):

If all we want is the unmangled type name for the purpose of logging, we can actually do this without using `std::type_info` or even RTTI at all.

A slightly portable solution that works for the big 3 main compiler front-ends ([gcc](/questions/tagged/gcc), [clang](/questions/tagged/clang), and [msvc](/questions/tagged/msvc)) would be to use a function `template` and extract the type name from the function name.

`gcc` and `clang` both offer `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` which is the name of a current function or function template with all type-argument in the string. Similarly MSVC has `__FUNCSIG__` which is equivalent. Each of these are formatted a little differently, for example, for a call of `void foo<int>`, the compilers will output something different:

- `gcc` is formatted `void foo() [with T = int; ]`
- `clang` is formatted `void foo() [T = int]`
- `msvc` is formatted `void foo<int>()`

Knowing this, it's just a matter of parsing out a prefix and suffix and wrapping this into a function in order to extract out the type name.

We can even use [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17)'s `std::string_view` and extended `constexpr` to get string names at **compile-time**, just by parsing the name of a template function. This could also be done in any earlier C++ version, but this will still require some form of string parsing.

For example:

```cpp
#include <string_view>

template <typename T>
constexpr auto get_type_name() -> std::string_view
{
#if defined(__clang__)
    constexpr auto prefix = std::string_view{"[T = "};
    constexpr auto suffix = "]";
    constexpr auto function = std::string_view{__PRETTY_FUNCTION__};
#elif defined(__GNUC__)
    constexpr auto prefix = std::string_view{"with T = "};
    constexpr auto suffix = "; ";
    constexpr auto function = std::string_view{__PRETTY_FUNCTION__};
#elif defined(_MSC_VER)
    constexpr auto prefix = std::string_view{"get_type_name<"};
    constexpr auto suffix = ">(void)";
    constexpr auto function = std::string_view{__FUNCSIG__};
#else
# error Unsupported compiler
#endif

    const auto start = function.find(prefix) + prefix.size();
    const auto end = function.find(suffix);
    const auto size = end - start;

    return function.substr(start, size);
}
```

With this, you can call `get_type_name<T>()` to get a `std::string_view` at compile-time indicating the unmangled type name.

For example:

```cpp
std::cout << get_type_name<std::string>() << std::endl;
```

on GCC will output:

```
std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>
```

and on clang will output:

```
std::basic_string<char>
```

<kbd>[Live Example](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/qo146d)</kbd>

---

A similar augmentation to this approach which avoids a `prefix` and `suffix` is to assume that the function name is the same for all types, and search for a sentinel type to parse out the offset to the sentinel from each end. This ensures that the string searching only happens once, and the offset is assumed to find the string name each time. For example, using `double` as a simple sentinel:

```cpp
template <typename T>
constexpr auto full_function_name() -> std::string_view
{
#if defined(__clang__) || defined(__GNUC__)
    return std::string_view{__PRETTY_FUNCTION__};
#elif defined(_MSC_VER)
    return std::string_view{__FUNCSIG__};
#else
# error Unsupported compiler
#endif
}

// Outside of the template so its computed once
struct type_name_info {
    static constexpr auto sentinel_function = full_function_name<double>();
    static constexpr auto prefix_offset = sentinel_function.find("double");
    static constexpr auto suffix_offset = sentinel_function.size() - prefix_offset - /* strlen("double") */ 6;
};

template <typename T>
constexpr auto get_type_name() -> std::string_view
{
    constexpr auto function = full_function_name<T>();

    const auto start = type_name_info::prefix_offset;
    const auto end = function.size() - type_name_info::suffix_offset;
    const auto size = end - start;

    return function.substr(start, size);
}
```

<kbd>[Live Example](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/33MG9fP5h)</kbd>

---

This isn't portable to *all* compilers, but can be modified for any compiler that offers a `__FUNCSIG__`/`__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` equivalent; it just requires a bit of parsing.

**note:** This hasn't been *fully* tested, so there may be some bugs; but the primary idea is to parse any output that contains the name in totality -- which is often a side-effect of `__func__`-like outputs on compilers.

Comment: Sad that even in 2021 it requires to much boiler-plate code just get get C++ demangling :-(

Comment: Agreed! Hopefully C++23 will finally include static reflection support, so people don't have to rely on this type of janky approach

Comment: In the code you provided, the `suffix_offset` value is calculated incorrectly. It is also necessary to add the length of the string `"double"` or, more simply, replace the entire expression with `sentinel_function.size() - prefix_offset - /* strlen("double") */ 6`.

Comment: @AlexeyIsmagilov good catch, thanks!

Comment: ftr the MSVC macro is `_MSC_VER`, not `__MSC_VER`.

Answer (score 11):

This is what we use.  HAVE_CXA_DEMANGLE is only set if available (recent versions of GCC only).

```
#ifdef HAVE_CXA_DEMANGLE
const char* demangle(const char* name)
{
   char buf[1024];
    unsigned int size=1024;
    int status;
    char* res = abi::__cxa_demangle (name,
                                 buf,
                                 &size,
                                 &status);
    return res;
  }
#else
const char* demangle(const char* name)
{
  return name;
}
#endif
```

Comment: You need to include `#include <cxxabi.h>`.

Comment: Interesting. I have __cxa_demangle without HAVE_CXA_DEMANGLE defined

Comment: @Matt What I meant to say is that our build system, based on autoconf, only sets HAVE_CXA_DEMANGLE if its available.

Comment: WARNING! The above code is likely to make the program crash. The buffer has to be either allocated by malloc or specified as NULL. Do NOT allocate it on the stack. See my code below.

Comment: watch out, res could return NULL :)

Answer (score 11):

Here, take a look at [type_strings.hpp](https://github.com/Eelis/geordi/blob/master/prelude/type_strings.hpp) it contains a function that does what you want.

If you just look for a demangling tool, which you e.g. could use to mangle stuff shown in a log file, take a look at `c++filt`, which comes with binutils. It can demangle C++ and Java symbol names.

Comment: Just to note, both cxa_demange() (which the code linked to uses) and cx++filt are gcc specific.  There is no portable way to do this.

Comment: c++filt doesn't cut it, I need this stuff (or most of it) at compile-time, mostly done with macros.

Comment: Link to type_strings.cpp seems broken.

Comment: Hi @GregoryPakosz The github link in your above comment seems broken too :( Cheers

Comment: Just an important FYI: `abi::__cxa_demangle()` and its ilk from `<cxxabi.h>` _**are not GCC-specific**_ – they may have been GCC-only in the distant past, but by this post’s time of writing, `<cxxabi.h>` was an entrenchedly ad-hoc standard. So while the answer’s code link was DOI, I can vouch for Clang providing first-class support in this case… q.v., from the Clang’s `libcxxabi` source: the respective decl, impl, huge test: http://git.io/vRTBo, http://git.io/vRTBh, http://git.io/vRTRf – the test code’s comments note the Clang implementation as capable of *more* demangling, somehow, vs. GCC.

Answer (score 5):

It's implementation defined, so it's not something that's going to be portable.  In MSVC++, name() is the undecorated name, and you have to look at raw_name() to get the decorated one.
Just a stab in the dark here, but under gcc, you might want to look at [demangle.h](http://hte.sourceforge.net/doxygenized-0.8.0pre1/demangle_8h.html)

Answer (score 4):

I also found a macro called `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__`, which does the trick. It gives a pretty function name (figures :)). This is what I needed.

I.e. it gives me the following:

```
virtual bool mutex::do_unlock()
```

But I don't think it works on other compilers.

Comment: Yes, __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ is gcc specific.

Answer (score 3):

The [accepted solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4541470/2707864) [1] works mostly well.
I found at least one case (and I wouldn't call it a corner case) where it does not report what I expected... with references.

For those cases, I found another solution, posted at the bottom.

**Problematic case** (using `type` as defined in [1]):

```
int i = 1;
cout << "Type of " << "i" << " is " << type(i) << endl;
int & ri = i;
cout << "Type of " << "ri" << " is " << type(ri) << endl;
```

produces

```
Type of i is int
Type of ri is int
```

**Solution** (using `type_name<decltype(obj)>()`, see code below):

```
cout << "Type of " << "i" << " is " << type_name<decltype(i)>() << endl;
cout << "Type of " << "ri" << " is " << type_name<decltype(ri)>() << endl;
```

produces

```
Type of i is int
Type of ri is int&
```

as desired (at least by me)

**Code**
.
It has to be in an included header, not in a separately compiled source, due to specialization issues. See [undefined reference to template function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10632251/undefined-reference-to-template-function) for instance.

```
#ifndef _MSC_VER
#   include <cxxabi.h>
#endif
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>

template <class T>
std::string
type_name()
{
    typedef typename std::remove_reference<T>::type TR;
    std::unique_ptr<char, void(*)(void*)> own
           (
#ifndef _MSC_VER
                abi::__cxa_demangle(typeid(TR).name(), nullptr,
                                           nullptr, nullptr),
#else
                nullptr,
#endif
                std::free
           );
    std::string r = own != nullptr ? own.get() : typeid(TR).name();
    if (std::is_const<TR>::value)
        r += " const";
    if (std::is_volatile<TR>::value)
        r += " volatile";
    if (std::is_lvalue_reference<T>::value)
        r += "&";
    else if (std::is_rvalue_reference<T>::value)
        r += "&&";
    return r;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Not a complete solution, but you may want to look at what some of the standard (or widely supported) macro's define.  It's common in logging code to see the use of the macros:

```
__FUNCTION__
__FILE__
__LINE__

e.g.:

log(__FILE__, __LINE__, __FUNCTION__, mymessage);
```

Comment: Not to mention __PRETTY_FUNCTION__.

Comment: This will give you the information about where you are in the code.  What the question was asking was a pretty name of a type, like std::vector.

Comment: He mentioned it was for debugging, and I stated it wasn't a complete solution.  Other macros such as __FUNCDNAME__ will return the decorated name.

Comment: Actually, re-reading the question, it was "I'm currently working on some logging code that supposed to - among other things - print information about the calling function."  This works.

Comment: It's not complete, since I don't know the namespace. This is allready in my code. But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2):

A slight variation on Ali's solution. If you want the code to still be very similar to

`typeid(bla).name()`,

writing this instead

`Typeid(bla).name()`    (differing only in capital first letter)

then you may be interested in this:

In file **type.hpp**

```
#ifndef TYPE_HPP
#define TYPE_HPP

#include <string>
#include <typeinfo>

std::string demangle(const char* name);

/*
template <class T>
std::string type(const T& t) {

  return demangle(typeid(t).name());
}
*/

class Typeid {
 public:

  template <class T>
    Typeid(const T& t) : typ(typeid(t)) {}

  std::string name() { return demangle(typ.name()); }

 private:
  const std::type_info& typ;
};


#endif
```

**type.cpp** stays same as in Ali's solution

Answer (score 2):

Following Ali's solution, here is the **C++11** templated alternative which worked best for my usage.

```cpp
// type.h
#include <cstdlib>
#include <memory>
#include <cxxabi.h>

template <typename T>
std::string demangle() {
  int status = -4;

  std::unique_ptr<char, void (*)(void*)> res{
      abi::__cxa_demangle(typeid(T).name(), NULL, NULL, &status), std::free};
  return (status == 0) ? res.get() : typeid(T).name();
}
```

Usage:

```cpp
// main.cpp
#include <iostream>

namespace test {
    struct SomeStruct {};
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << demangle<double>() << std::endl;
    std::cout << demangle<const int&>() << std::endl;
    std::cout << demangle<test::SomeStruct>() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Will print:

```cpp
double                                                                        
int                                                                           
test::SomeStruct
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at `__cxa_demangle` which you can find at `cxxabi.h`.

Comment: I took, it's deprecated, according to the message I get.

Comment: Where did you find that message? I just googled it and it seems to be supported, no evidence of being deprecated.

Comment: Maybe it's deprecated in :: namespace. Use abi::__cxa_demangle and you won't get a warning. What gcc are you using?

Answer (score 1):

```
// KeithB's solution is good, but has one serious flaw in that unless buf is static
// it'll get trashed from the stack before it is returned in res - and will point who-knows-where
// Here's that problem fixed, but the code is still non-re-entrant and not thread-safe.
// Anyone care to improve it?

#include <cxxabi.h>

// todo: javadoc this properly
const char* demangle(const char* name)
{
    static char buf[1024];
    size_t size = sizeof(buf);
    int status;
    // todo:
    char* res = abi::__cxa_demangle (name,
                                 buf,
                                 &size,
                                 &status);
    buf[sizeof(buf) - 1] = 0; // I'd hope __cxa_demangle does this when the name is huge, but just in case.
    return res;
  }
```

Comment: WARNING! The buffer has to be either allocated by malloc or specified as NULL. Do NOT allocate it on the stack. See my code below.

Answer (score 0):

I've always wanted to use type_info, but I'm sure that the result of the name() member function is non-standard and won't necessarily return anything that can be converted to a meaningful result.
If you are sticking to one compiler, there maybe a compiler specific function that will do what you want.  Check the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

`boost::typeindex` provides something helpful.

```cpp
#include <boost/type_index.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Widget {};

int main() {
  using boost::typeindex::type_id_with_cvr;
  const std::vector<Widget> vw;
  std::cout << type_id_with_cvr<decltype(vw)>().pretty_name() << std::endl;
  std::cout << type_id_with_cvr<decltype(vw[0])>().pretty_name() << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
std::vector<Widget, std::allocator<Widget> > const
Widget const&
```

What is worthy of notice is that `type_id_with_cvr` preserves reference and c/v qualifiers, while `typeid` doesn't. See the following example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/type_index.hpp>
#include <typeindex>
#include <vector>
#include <typeinfo>

class Widget {};

template <typename T>
void f(const T &param) {
  std::cout << typeid(param).name() << std::endl;
  std::cout
      << boost::typeindex::type_id_with_cvr<decltype(param)>().pretty_name()
      << std::endl;
}

int main() {
  const std::vector<Widget> vw(1);
  f(&vw[0]);
  return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
PK6Widget
Widget const* const&
```

Here, `typeid` produces `PK6Widget`, which means **P**ointer to **K**onst Widget. The number '6' is the length of the name 'Widget'. This is not the correct type of `param`, in which the reference and const qualifier are dropped.

The `type_id_with_cvr` actually uses the demangling functions in `boost::core`, as has been mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34916852/8395081). To preserve the cv qualifiers or reference, it just defines an empty template named `cvr_saver` and then passes `cvr_saver<type>` to `typeid`.

*Effective Modern C++* Item 4 talks about this.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to read the output of your program that print `typeid(XXX).name()` for debugging purpose, you can use **`c++filt -t`** on command line to demangle the output easily:

```bash
$ ./program | c++filt -t
```

For example:

```bash
$ echo 'St6vectorIiSaIiEE' | c++filt -t
std::vector<int, std::allocator<int>>
```