# Get functions names in a shared library programmatically

Tags: c++, c, linux, shared-libraries, dlopen

Can I get list of all functions names from a shared library (Linux only) programmatically when I am using `dl_open()`?

I want something like this:

```
std::vector<std::string> list_all_functions(void *dl) { 
   //... what can I do here?
}

int main() {
    void * dl = dl_open("./mylib.so", RTLD_NOW);
    auto functions = list_all_functions(dl);
    //...
    dl_close(dl);
    return 0;
}
```

---

Example library (mylib.so)

Header (.h):

```
extern "C" {
    int sum (int a, int b);
}
```

Source (.c):

```
int sum (int a, int b) { return a + b; }
```

---

Dirty hack that I know: use `nm` or `objdump` utility

Comment: check out `man elf` for the ELF API. There are various implementations such as https://fedorahosted.org/elfutils/ or http://sourceforge.net/p/elftoolchain/wiki/libelf/

Comment: Even if you got the list of names, how would you call them if you don't know what parameters they take?

Comment: @MarkB , in my project, all functions have same signature, but there is other [method to call function without specified signature](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1354537/dlsym-dlopen-with-runtime-arguments)

Comment: @AlexBar for your own project you can create a special function that lists all available ones in a module.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no libc function to do that. However, you can write one yourself (or copy/paste the code from a tool like readelf).

On Linux, `dlopen()` returns the address of a `link_map` structure, which has a member named `l_addr` that points to the base address of the loaded shared object (assuming your system doesn't randomize shared library placement, and that your library has not been  prelinked).

On Linux, a way to find the base address (the address of `Elf*_Ehdr`) is to use `dl_iterate_phdr()` after `dlopen()`ing the library.

Having the ELF header, you should be able to iterate over a list of exported symbols (the dynamic symbol table), by first locating the `Elf*_Phdr` of type `PT_DYNAMIC`, and then locating `DT_SYMTAB`, `DT_STRTAB` entries, and iterating over all symbols in the dynamic symbol table. Use `/usr/include/elf.h` to guide you.

Additionally, you could use [libelf](http://www.mr511.de/software/english.html), that I don't know very well personally.

However, note that you'll get a list of defined functions, but you'll have no idea how to call them.

Answer (score 10):

**UPDATE | TL;DR :**

I actually found shorter way:

```
    auto library = dlopen("/path/to/lib.so", RTLD_LAZY | RTLD_GLOBAL);
    const char * libname = "lib.so";
    struct link_map * map = nullptr;
    dlinfo(library, RTLD_DI_LINKMAP, &map);

    Elf64_Sym * symtab = nullptr;
    char * strtab = nullptr;
    int symentries = 0;
    for (auto section = map->l_ld; section->d_tag != DT_NULL; ++section)
    {
        if (section->d_tag == DT_SYMTAB)
        {
            symtab = (Elf64_Sym *)section->d_un.d_ptr;
        }
        if (section->d_tag == DT_STRTAB)
        {
            strtab = (char*)section->d_un.d_ptr;
        }
        if (section->d_tag == DT_SYMENT)
        {
            symentries = section->d_un.d_val;
        }
    }
    int size = strtab - (char *)symtab;
    for (int k = 0; k < size / symentries; ++k)
    {
        auto sym = &symtab[k];
        // If sym is function
        if (ELF64_ST_TYPE(symtab[k].st_info) == STT_FUNC)
        {
            //str is name of each symbol
            auto str = &strtab[sym->st_name];
            printf("%s\n", str);
        }
    }
```

**OLD**

I believe author does not need this anymore but maybe someone need actual code and here it is (based on previous answer)

First, we need a callback for `dl_iterate_phdr()`:

```
static int callback(struct dl_phdr_info *info, size_t size, void *data)
{
    // data is copy of 2nd arg in dl_iterate_phdr
    // you can use it for your lib name as I did
    const char * libname = (const char *)data;

    // if current elf's name contains your lib
    if (strstr(info->dlpi_name, libname))
    {

        printf("loaded %s from: %s\n", libname, info->dlpi_name);

        for (int j = 0; j < info->dlpi_phnum; j++)
        {
            // we need to save dyanmic section since it contains symbolic table
            if (info->dlpi_phdr[j].p_type == PT_DYNAMIC)
            {
                Elf64_Sym * symtab = nullptr;
                char * strtab = nullptr;
                int symentries = 0;
                auto dyn = (Elf64_Dyn *)(info->dlpi_addr + info->dlpi_phdr[j].p_vaddr);
                for (int k = 0; k < info->dlpi_phdr[j].p_memsz / sizeof(Elf64_Dyn); ++k)
                {
                    if (dyn[k].d_tag == DT_SYMTAB)
                    {
                        symtab = (Elf64_Sym *)dyn[k].d_un.d_ptr;
                    }
                    if (dyn[k].d_tag == DT_STRTAB)
                    {
                        strtab = (char*)dyn[k].d_un.d_ptr;
                    }
                    if (dyn[k].d_tag == DT_SYMENT)
                    {
                        symentries = dyn[k].d_un.d_val;
                    }
                }
                int size = strtab - (char *)symtab;
                // for each string in table
                for (int k = 0; k < size / symentries; ++k)
                {
                    auto sym = &symtab[k];
                    auto str = &strtab[sym->st_name];
                    printf("%s\n", str);
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Next, we call `dl_iterate_phdr()`:

```
int main()
{
    auto library = dlopen("/path/to/library.so", RTLD_LAZY | RTLD_GLOBAL);
    const char * libname = "library.so";
    dl_iterate_phdr(callback, (void*)libname);
    return 0;
}
```

If you need to store those names somewhere, you can pass a pointer to your container, restore it with cast and write there.

For my example library:

```
#include "simple_lib.h"

#include <cstdio>

void __attribute__ ((constructor)) initLibrary(void)
{
    printf("Library is initialized\n");
}
void __attribute__ ((destructor)) cleanUpLibrary(void)
{

    printf("Library is exited\n");
}

void make_number()
{
    printf("1\n");
}
```

Prints this:

```
Library is initialized

_ITM_deregisterTMCloneTable
puts
__gmon_start__
_ITM_registerTMCloneTable
__cxa_finalize
_Z11initLibraryv
make_number
_Z14cleanUpLibraryv
Library is exited
```