# Can I ungarble GCC's RTTI names?

Tags: c++, g++, rtti, name-mangling

Using gcc, when I ask for an object/variable's type using typeid, I get a different result from the type_info::name method from what I'd expect to get on Windows. I Googled around a bit, and found out that RTTI names are implementation-specific.

Problem is, I want to get a type's name as it would be returned on Windows. Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If it's what you're asking, there is no compiler switch that would make gcc behave like msvc regarding the name returned by `type_info::name()`.

However, in your code you can rely on the gcc specific `__cxa_demangle` function.

There is in fact [an answer on SO that addresses your problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/281818/unmangling-the-result-of-stdtypeinfoname/281876#281876).

Reference: [libstdc++ manual, Chapter 40. Demangling](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/ext_demangling.html).

Answer (score 1):

c++ function names really include all the return and argument type information as well as the class and method name.   When compiled, they are 'mangled' into a standard form (standard for each compiler) that can act as an assembler symbol and includes all the type information.

You need to run a function or program to reverse this mangling, called a *demangler*.

try running

```
c++filt myoutput.txt
```

on the output of the function.  This *demangles* the real symbol name back into a human readable form.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this other question [Is there an online name demangler for C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3006438/is-there-an-online-name-demangler-for-c) I've written a online tool for this: [c++filtjs](http://d.fuqu.jp/c++filtjs/)