# Is there an online name demangler for C++?

Tags: c++, demangler

I'm getting a fairly long and confusing link error, and would love it if I could just paste it into some textbox on some website and have the names un-mangled for me.

Does anyone know of such a service?

Comment: Btw, what is your compiler? Maybe you just can use a ready tool shipped with it.

Comment: I've found "undname.exe" and it did the job for VC++.

Comment: paste your name here, and if it's a VC2005 name I'll demangle it.

Comment: No online requirement: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4468770/c-name-mangling-decoder-for-g

Answer (score 165, accepted):

I have created such an online serivice: https://demangler.com

This is a gcc c++ symbol demangler. You just copy a stack trace, or the output of nm into a text box, and it will return the output with the names demangled.

@Update: It now demangles MSVC and Java symbols also.

Comment: This one worked for me, but not the one in the more popular answer: _ZN9cdnalizer11rewriteHTMLINS_6apache8IteratorEcEET_RKSsRKNS_6ConfigES3_S3_St8functionIFS3_RKS3_SB_EES9_IFvSsEE

Comment: Your demangler cannot demangle ref qualifiers for Itanium. I am looking at _ZNR4test1fEv generated by Clang.

Comment: Thanks, nice site! Could you please add `white-space: normal` or similar to the responseSection <pre> tag (and maybe add line numbers)? Long one-line output isn't readable currently.

Comment: You should be careful. Most real-world implementations of demanglers are horribly buggy and insecure. They basically only work on mangled names that the same platform produced, but may run into high complexity or flat out memory errors on general inputs.

Comment: Nice site. Have you considered making it "reactive"? Needing to re-paste mangled names on every submission gets cumbersome. You could probably just recompute on every change too.

Comment: Link broken... :(

Comment: site no longer up

Comment: It been up for many years - and is up now. Very occasionally the site is down for a few minutes. Whenever that happens it tends to generate comments on SO.

Comment: @RafaelBaptista understood. Also, just to let you know, your site's certificate is expired :)

Comment: It did not translate `__unwindfunclet` to `~` for destructor (MSVC-2015, delete this comment once fixed).
Still better than the other answer, which just says "Not a mangled C++ symbol".

Comment: The hacker's solution (in the sense of "it's a hack, but it works") is to substitute the mangled name into `extern "C" int YOURNAMEHERE = 0;` on Godbolt and then "Output > Demangle identifiers" in the assembly output. For example: https://godbolt.org/z/Mvh3xaoY8  (Works only for Itanium ABI, I suppose; MSVC's mangled names aren't valid identifiers.)

Comment: Link broken (bad ssl cert)

Answer (score 111):

I created one based on this question. It works with the inputs I tried on, supports g++ and msvc++ via `__cxa_demangle` and `__unDName`, compiled to Javascript via Emscripten.

Here it is: [c++filtjs](http://d.fuqu.jp/c++filtjs/).

Comment: Awesome! Thank you! Perhaps mention "Online C++ name demangler" somewhere on the page, so that people can find you via Google?

Comment: Is it possible to extend this tool for other OS? I wanted to particularly look forward to port it for AIX, Solaris and HPUX

Comment: very nice indeed, but I would like a small C source instead.

Comment: @Zibri: a "small C source" is not online. For that, use the existing c++filt and undname utilities.

Comment: @Abhijit: It's not about an OS, it's about _toolchains_.  g++ and msvc++ for instance.

Comment: @nattofriends: Your tool doesn't seem to escape brackets, see `??_R3?$KxSet@V?$KxSpe@DI@@I@@8`.

Comment: @nattofriends Template parameters seem to be lost in cases such as `_Z6kernelIfLj3EEvPT_5arrayIPKS0_XT0_EES5_S2_IjXT0_EES6_S0_`, although for `_Z8positionILj3EE5arrayIjXT_EERKS1_` the parameter of the function *is* displayed properly (probably because it starts with a number and therefore can't be an html tag)

Comment: Jup, definitely the escaping, just added [htmlEncode.js](http://www.tumuski.com/code/htmlencode/) and replaced `$("#out").html("<pre>"+out+"</pre>");` by `$("#out").html("<pre>"+htmlEncode(out)+"</pre>");` and now templates are displayed correctly

Comment: Thanks Joe, I'll do that soon.

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could fix your issue with templates that others have mentioned. This has caused at least one [spurious question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21284752/g-name-mangling-slightly-different) on SO.

Answer (score 42):

Many C++ compilers come with a built-in tool which does precisely what you are looking for:

- GCC: [`c++filt`](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/binutils/c_002b_002bfilt.html)
- Clang/LLVM: [`llvm-cxxfilt`](https://llvm.org/docs/CommandGuide/llvm-cxxfilt.html)
- MSVC: [`undname`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/decorated-names#Undecorated)

Comment: I want it with minimum effort as opposed to with a mouse click :) Oh well, I don't need it very often anyway.

Comment: my usual use case for c++filt is `objdump -dr ./AClass.o | c++filt | less` (disassembler) or `nm ./AClass.o | c++filt | less` (list of symbols inside of the object file)

Comment: Most compilers aren't GCC. Compilers that aren't GCC do not ship c++filt. By induction, most compilers do not ship c++filt.

Comment: `echo "<mangled content>" | c++filt`

Comment: **GCC**: [`c++filt`](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/binutils/c_002b_002bfilt.html) **Clang/LLVM**: [`llvm-cxxfilt`](https://llvm.org/docs/CommandGuide/llvm-cxxfilt.html) **MSVC**: [`undname`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/decorated-names#Undecorated).

Comment: Thanks @CameronTacklind, I edited this into the answer now to make it even more useful.

Answer (score 11):

There are two copy-and-paste online solutions:

- [demangler.com](http://demangler.com/), which supports GCC, Visual Studio, or Java symbols
- [c++filtjs](http://pear.warosu.org/c++filtjs/), which supports GCC and Visual Studio but [has problems with template parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21284752/two-mangled-names-demangling-to-the-same-function-signature)

If you only need support for GCC and Clang, you also have the option of using [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com), which is probably the most versatile [online C++ compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3916000/online-c-compiler-and-evaluator).

This is not quite as simple as cut, paste, and click - but not too much harder - and it looks like there are no issues with template parameters as was noted above. You just need to modify the command line to run something like this:

```
cat main.cpp | c++filt -t
```

[See it live with this example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=1f6a62b50acf765dad0b3b741d4c3432-ee104f1fb9ed1ebc8772dc9a7f5abf22) which demangles:

```
_Z6kernelIfLj3EEvPT_5arrayIPKS0_XT0_EES5_S2_IjXT0_EES6_S0_
```

to:

```
void kernel<float, 3u>(float*, array<float const*, 3u>, array<float const*, 3u>, array<unsigned int, 3u>, array<unsigned int, 3u>, float)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: `echo 'N3sdf3v125WorldE'| c++filt -t` greatly produces `sdf::v12::World` to me.

Answer (score 2):

FYI, there's also a Ruby gem to demangle Borland/MS/whatever mangled names: [unmangler](https://github.com/zed-0xff/unmangler)