# C++ name mangling decoder for g++?

Tags: c++, name-mangling, name-decoration

is there any C++ name-mangling decoder for g++?

Comment: Some guys will soon answer `c++filt`

Comment: Voting to reopen:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4465872/why-does-typeid-name-return-weird-characters-using-gcc-and-how-to-make-it-prin clearly requires it to be from inside the code, and only for types, which never appear on object files (as opposed to functions). This one is usually interpreted as "on object files from the command line".

Comment: it old but I have been helped by this site a lot https://demangler.com/

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You can use c++filt to demangle c++ symbols.  For instance

```
$ c++filt -n _Z1fv
f()
```

Answer (score 14):

c++filt, example usage here:

[Can we see the template instantiated code by C++ compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4448094/can-we-see-the-template-instantiated-code-by-c-compiler/4448160#4448160)

Answer (score 6):

You may also be interested on the `-C` option of `objdump`:

```
objdump -CSr main.o
```

which demangles relocation references like:

```
  char *sn = new char[4];
10:   bf 04 00 00 00          mov    $0x4,%edi
15:   e8 00 00 00 00          callq  1a <main+0x1a>
                      16: R_X86_64_PC32       operator new[](unsigned long)-0x4
```

Without `-C` it would show the mangled name `_Znam`.

See also: [Can objdump un-mangle names of C++ template functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9419228/can-objdump-un-mangle-names-of-c-template-functions)

There are also some online demanglers mentioned at [Is there an online name demangler for C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3006438/is-there-an-online-name-demangler-for-c) like http://demangler.com/ If it exists, there is SaaS of it.

`nm` also has a `-C` option.

Comment: or even `objdump -CSr main.o | less --pattern=_Znam`

Answer (score 1):

you have c++filt. Recently I found an online tool as well.

1.

```
c++filt [-_|--strip-underscore]
        [-n|--no-strip-underscore]
        [-p|--no-params]
        [-t|--types]
        [-i|--no-verbose]
        [-r|--no-recurse-limit]
        [-R|--recurse-limit]
        [-s format|--format=format]
        [--help]  [--version]  [symbol…]
```

Example:
c++filt symbol

[for more info](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/binutils/c_002b_002bfilt.html)

2. Online solution
   [visit](https://demangler.com/)