# Can objdump un-mangle names of C++ template functions?

Tags: c++, gcc, name-mangling, objdump

I have a C++ object file that contains instantiations of some C++ template functions. The object file in question instantiates the same function for a few different combinations of template parameters. I'm trying to debug a problem and would like to look at the disassembly of a specific instantiation of the template function (that is, I know the template parameters for the function that I want to examine).  I would typically do this using `objdump` to disassemble the object file, but it (at least by default) isn't able to de-mangle the C++ function names. Is there any way to do this? The object files were created using gcc 4.6.1.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Pipe it through `c++filt`? Might need to give it `-n` depending on whether the symbols come w/ or w/o the leading underscore.

Comment: Looks like that would work. I also just found the `-C` option for `objdump`, which seems to work for my application at least.

Comment: @JasonR even better. Historically there have been options and variant names like `nm++` but they were hit and miss and I got into the habit of just piping everything.

Comment: @JasonR, thanks for posting this... `-C` was undocumented in my version of `objdump` (not shown with `--help`) but it still worked.

Answer (score 37):

**`objdump -C`**

The `-C` flag enables demangling:

```
printf '
template<typename T>
T add(T x, T y) {
    return x + y;
}

void h() {
    add(1, 2);
    add(1.0, 2.0);
}
' > a.cpp
g++ -g -std=c++11 a.cpp
objdump -CS a.out
```

The output contains demangled names:

```
int main() {
    add(1, 2);
 60c:   e8 28 00 00 00          callq  639 <int add<int>(int, int)>
    add(1.0, 2.0);
 62d:   e8 1b 00 00 00          callq  64d <double add<double>(double, double)>

0000000000000639 <int add<int>(int, int)>:

000000000000064d <double add<double>(double, double)>:
```

Without `-C`, it contains mangled names instead:

```
0000000000000639 <_Z3addIiET_S0_S0_>:
000000000000064d <_Z3addIdET_S0_S0_>:
```

`man objdump` says:

> Decode (demangle) low-level symbol names into user-level names.  Besides removing any initial underscore prepended by the system, this makes C++ function names readable.  Different compilers have different mangling styles. The optional demangling style argument can be used to choose an appropriate demangling style for your compiler.

`nm` also has the `-C` option.

Tested in Ubuntu 18.04, `g++` 7.3.0, `objdump` 2.30.