# g++ name mangling of extern variable names

Tags: c++, g++, extern, name-mangling

Having simple file
a.cpp:

```
//a.cpp
extern const int n = 8;
const int b = 10;
```

Compiling with:
`g++ -c a.cpp -fPIC`

And checking with `readelf -sw`:

```
Symbol table '.symtab' contains 11 entries:
Num:    Value          Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
...
6: 0000000000000004     4 OBJECT  LOCAL  DEFAULT    4 _ZL1b
...
9: 0000000000000000     4 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT    4 n
...
```

Why is the `b` const int name mangled, but the extern global variable const int `n` name not mangled?

Does standard define this behaviour (not mangling the name) or is it `g++` feature?

Comment: Ever-helpful Wikipedia offers an overview of [Name Mangling In C++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling#Name_mangling_in_C.2B.2B), where you can read about it not being in the standard (for instance).  As for why it would mangle a local...I don't know; I skimmed the question too fast and scrolled down and thought b was a function from the table.  Must be an answer, though.

Comment: Already answered mangling is compiler spefific thing; you can read more from that question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4468770/c-name-mangling-decoder-for-g