# Is there any way to convert symbol names into function names?

Tags: c++, decompiler

For example
`callq 401400 <_ZNSaIcEC1Ev@plt>`
I want to know the name of this function

My compiler is g++

Comment: https://demangler.com/

Comment: [or this one, linking the other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4468770/c-name-mangling-decoder-for-g)

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `c++filt` tool that should be included with your compiler.  Example:

```
$ echo 'callq 401400 <_ZNSaIcEC1Ev@plt>' | c++filt
callq 401400 <std::allocator<char>::allocator()@plt>
```

Comment: see my dupe tag