# Two mangled names demangling to the same function signature

Tags: c++, g++, name-mangling

I have a spidermonkey library that exports the following mangled symbol fora function `JS_DefineProperty`:

```
_Z17JS_DefinePropertyP9JSContextP8JSObjectPKcN2JS5ValueEPFiS0_NS5_6HandleIS2_EENS7_I4jsidEENS5_13MutableHandleIS6_EEEPFiS0_S8_SA_iSC_Ej
```

When I try to compile a file that uses this function, the external reference is compiled as:

```
_Z17JS_DefinePropertyP9JSContextP8JSObjectPKcN2JS5ValueEPFiS0_NS5_6HandleIS2_EENS7_IlEENS5_13MutableHandleIS6_EEEPFiS0_S8_S9_iSB_Ej
```

The end of the name is slightly different between the two. I ran both through a name demangler and they both come out to the same signature:

```
JS_DefineProperty(JSContext*, JSObject*, char const*, JS::Value, int (*)(JSContext*, JS::Handle, JS::Handle, JS::MutableHandle), int (*)(JSContext*, JS::Handle, JS::Handle, int, JS::MutableHandle), unsigned int)
```

So I'm a little stumped as to what the difference is. I believe both versions were compiled using `g++ 4.7`.
Can anyone decode the extra difference in the name, so I can investigate further?

Comment: according to http://pear.warosu.org/c++filtjs/ they decode to the same signature.

Comment: @fritzone the website is wrong because it incorrectly escapes the templates (thinking they are html)

Comment: Yup... That's an interesting remark. Who reports this to that site?

Comment: @fritzone it does not seem like there is a way to report it which is unfortunate since obviously people are using it to figure things out and we have at least one spurious SO question b/c the tool is broken.

Comment: @fritzone actually the owner [can be contacted and has been](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3006438/is-there-an-online-name-demangler-for-c). Take a look at the comments below the accepted answer. Also, make sure to downvote it or comment to remind him to fix this! The other answers there look useful. And use [this one](http://demangler.com/) instead

Comment: @user3125280 I forgot about that question and it is funny since I provided an answer to it as well. I recommended using `c++filt` on Coliru in that question which would not have the same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is in fact a difference between the two.

`_Z17JS_DefinePropertyP9JSContextP8JSObjectPKcN2JS5ValueEPFiS0_NS5_6HandleIS2_EENS7_I4jsidEENS5_13MutableHandleIS6_EEEPFiS0_S8_SA_iSC_Ej` demangles to :

```
JS_DefineProperty(JSContext*, JSObject*, char const*, JS::Value, int (*)(JSContext*, JS::Handle<JSObject*>, JS::Handle<jsid>, JS::MutableHandle<JS::Value>), int (*)(JSContext*, JS::Handle<JSObject*>, JS::Handle<jsid>, int, JS::MutableHandle<JS::Value>), unsigned int)
```

`_Z17JS_DefinePropertyP9JSContextP8JSObjectPKcN2JS5ValueEPFiS0_NS5_6HandleIS2_EENS7_IlEENS5_13MutableHandleIS6_EEEPFiS0_S8_S9_iSB_Ej` demangles to :

```
JS_DefineProperty(JSContext*, JSObject*, char const*, JS::Value, int (*)(JSContext*, JS::Handle<JSObject*>, JS::Handle<long>, JS::MutableHandle<JS::Value>), int (*)(JSContext*, JS::Handle<JSObject*>, JS::Handle<long>, int, JS::MutableHandle<JS::Value>), unsigned int)
```

Where the former is using `JS::Handle<jsid>`, the latter is using `JS::Handle<long>`.

Comment: I get these resultss with c++filt as well, I assume that's how you got them? Maybe http://pear.warosu.org/c++filtjs/ doesn't work perfectly, even though it uses c++filt...

Comment: haha [it's a html thing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3006438/is-there-an-online-name-demangler-for-c) it must think the templates are tags

Comment: @user3125280 : that's correct - I used [c++filt](http://linux.die.net/man/1/c++filt) on my Linux system.

Comment: Thank you! I was indeed using pear.warosu.org/c++filtjs