# How to unmangle mangled names of C++ lambdas?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, name-mangling

After compilation with `g++-4.9.3 -std=c++11` the code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
using namespace std;
int main() { cout << typeid([]{}).name() << endl; }
```

outputs `Z4mainEUlvE_` as the mangled name of the given lambda on Linux x86_64. However, the `c++filt` tool is unable to unmangle it. It just outputs the input given to it, `Z4mainEUlvE_`.

How do I unmangle it?

Comment: What do you expect the output to be? `[]()`?

Comment: lambda: an unnamed function object capable of capturing variables in scope. What would you like the name to be?

Comment: @richard And two lambdas, known as `bob` of course.

Comment: Have you tried to use c++filt with '-t' option? My c++filt also was unable to demangle your lambda type without it...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use GCC's special `abi::__cxa_demangle` function:

```
#include <memory>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cxxabi.h>
#include <iostream>

// delete malloc'd memory
struct malloc_deleter
{
    void operator()(void* p) const { std::free(p); }
};

// custom smart pointer for c-style strings allocated with std::malloc
using cstring_uptr = std::unique_ptr<char, malloc_deleter>;

int main()
{
    // special function to de-mangle names
    int error;
    cstring_uptr name(abi::__cxa_demangle(typeid([]{}).name(), 0, 0, &error));

    if(!error)
        std::cout << name.get() << '\n';
    else if(error == -1)
        std::cerr << "memory allocation failed" << '\n';
    else if(error == -2)
        std::cerr << "not a valid mangled name" << '\n';
    else if(error == -3)
        std::cerr << "bad argument" << '\n';
}
```

**Output:**

```
main::{lambda()#1}
```

According to [The Documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/libstdc++-html-USERS-4.3/a01696.html) this function returns a c-style *zero-terminated* string allocated using [std::malloc](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/c/malloc) which the caller needs to free using [std::free](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/c/free). This example uses a *smart pointer* to free the returned string automatically at the end of the scope.

Answer (score 10):

Using `c++filt` version `070207 20070207`:

```
$ c++filt -n Z4mainEUlvE_
main::'lambda'()
```

Although as the commenters have suggested, these names aren't always entirely helpful.

Comment: Alternatively you can just pipe the output of the program to `c++filt`, like `./a.out | c++filt`

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need it inside your code, and its only for fun then use an online tool like http://d.fuqu.jp/c++filtjs/ which for `Z4mainEUlvE_` it returns `main::{lambda()#1}`.

Other tools can be found under [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3006438/is-there-an-online-name-demangler-for-c).

Answer (score 1):

You could try using `boost::core::demangle` but I don't know if your results will be any different.

For example

```
#include <boost/core/demangle.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main () {
  std::cout  << boost::core::demangle (typeid ([](){}).name ()) << std::endl;
}
```