# What does "Z4mainE2" mean?

Tags: c++, typeid

```
#include<iostream>
#include<typeinfo>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    class c1{
        public:
        int a ;

    };

c1 obj1;
cout<<typeid(obj1).name();  
}
```

I ran it on [ideone](https://ideone.co/m/VznKAf)  and the `typeid.name()` returns `Z4mainE2c1`. It becomes apparent that `c1` is the name of the class but what is `Z4mainE2`.
**Why is it not displaying the type name only?**

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling . Note that the exact string produced by `std::type_info::name()` is not prescribed by the standard. A compiler is free to produce whatever's convenient.

Comment: The [`typeid`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid) operator returns a [`std::type_info`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info) structure whose [`name()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info/name) member function returns a ***implementation defined*** null terminated string. Exactly what the contents of the string will be is not specified. In your case it seems to be a *mangled* type name.

Comment: As for the actual string you get, like you said the "c1" part is easy to decipher, but so should the "main" part also be, since `c1` is defined inside the `main` function.

Comment: `4main` means the function named `main` with length of 4, `2c1` is an identifier named `c1` (length of 2). you can demangle that with many tools like [demangler.com](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3006438/995714) or [c++filt](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4939636/995714)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Z4mainE2` is the result of ["name mangling"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling). Basically, C++ compilers are designed around a linker model which doesn't directly support things like function overloading, operators, or even class members. To support the various non-C features of C++, object code produced by the compiler adds special sequences to the generated names. While the mangled names aren't generally visible or important to the programmer, the `typeinfo` object on some platforms exposes them directly.