# typeinfo / typeid output

Tags: c++, gcc, types

I'm currently trying to debug a piece of simple code and wish to see how a specific variable type changes during the program.

I'm using the typeinfo header file so I can utilise typeid.name(). I'm aware that typeid.name() is compiler specific thus the output might not be particularly helpful or standard.

I'm using `GCC` but I cannot find a list of the potential output despite searching, assuming a list of typeid output symbols exist. I don't want to do any sort of casting based on the output or manipulate any kind of data, just follow its type.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

int main()
{ 
    int a = 10;
    cout << typeid(int).name() << endl;
}
```

Is there a symbol list anywhere?

Comment: it might be worth noting that it's GCC bundled with MinGW.

Comment: if you just want to follow types, then how about `if (typeid(a) == typeid(int)) { /* action */ }`?

Comment: What are you trying to do? What do you mean by symbol list exactly?

Comment: "... variable type changes...". Er... In C++ variable types never change. Variable always have the type it was first declared with.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unmangling the result of std::type_info::name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/281818/unmangling-the-result-of-stdtype-infoname)

Comment: I'm checking whether something has a remainder or not. I was passing the modulus operator a double for its left operand thus an error. The code I finally got working is using vector<T>::size_type. This is being defined as a double but it works when passed as a modulus operand. Which is why I want to check the type later on.  As for symbols, I just mean the not-too-cryptic output letters GCC decides to use.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I don't know if such a list exists, but you can make a small program to print them out:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

#define PRINT_NAME(x) std::cout << #x << " - " << typeid(x).name() << '\n'

int main()
{
    PRINT_NAME(char);
    PRINT_NAME(signed char);
    PRINT_NAME(unsigned char);
    PRINT_NAME(short);
    PRINT_NAME(unsigned short);
    PRINT_NAME(int);
    PRINT_NAME(unsigned int);
    PRINT_NAME(long);
    PRINT_NAME(unsigned long);
    PRINT_NAME(float);
    PRINT_NAME(double);
    PRINT_NAME(long double);
    PRINT_NAME(char*);
    PRINT_NAME(const char*);
    //...
}
```

Comment: many thanks, not too sure why this didn't cross my mind. This works perfectly.

Comment: `template< typename T > void PRINT_NAME() { std::cout << … }`

Comment: @Potatoswatter and how do you stringify T ? you're solution is less powerful than Bens's.

Comment: why does `PRINT_NAME(long double)` outputs `e`. What sintax is that `#` in front of `x` variable?