# How can I call functions from one .cpp file in another .cpp file?

Tags: c++

I tried looking this up and got mixed results using header files and such.

Basically I have multiple .cpp files with all my functions I made for use with binary trees, [BST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree), linked lists, etc.

Instead of having to copy and paste functions as I need them, I want to just be able to do a:

```
#include <myBSTFunctions.h>
```

And be able to call and use my own functions.

What are the steps to accomplish this?
Make a header file with all the function prototypes I used?

And where should I place the .cpp and header file with all the actually functions?

Is there a way I can call the directory of the functions file directly?

I.e., I'm more thinking of having it in the same folder with the main source .cpp file to share with some of my colleagues.

How can I accomplish this?

On Windows and the [MinGW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MinGW) compiler.

Comment: platform? toolchain?

Comment: Helpful reading: [How does the compilation/linking process work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6264249/how-does-the-compilation-linking-process-work). Exactly how this works differs from  compiler tool chain to tool chain. For g++ it can be as simple as `g++ A.cpp B.cpp`

Comment: How will the compiler know where to find a.cpp?

Comment: Also, reading a book on C++ might assist in understanding multi-file programs: [here are a few nice ones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: "How will the compiler know where to find a.cpp? " If it's not in the current working directory you have to tell the compiler where it is `g++ A.cpp ../../source/b/B.cpp` says look for A.cpp in the current folder and to find B.cpp, go back two folders and look in source/b.

Comment: Loads of duplicate questions must exist among the [762,341 C++ questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) and [378,428 C questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c).

Comment: Normally all functions declared within a cpp file have external linkage by default, i.e a function defined in one file can be used in another cpp file by forward declaration. (So by #including the .h file you get the forward declaration of the function that you want to call that lives in another cpp file.)

However, using the `static` keyword before the function declaration limits its linkage to internal , i.e a static function cannot be used within a file outside of its definition.

Answer (score 27):

Declare functions in a header:

```
// File MyFunctions.h
int myFunction1(int, int);
int myFunction2(int, int);
```

---

Implement them in file MyFunctions.cpp:

```
// File MyFunctions.cpp
#include "MyFunctions.h"
int myFunction1(int a, int b){
    // Your code

int myFunction2(int a, int b){
    // Your code
}
```

---

Include the header in whatever file you want:

```
// OtherFile.cpp
#include "MyFunctions.h"
// Now you have access to the functions defined in MyFunctions.h in this file
```

---

I don’t know MinGW, but it should look something like:

```
g++ otherfile.cpp MyFunctions.cpp...
```

Comment: thanks! I'm finally starting to realize why/how this works (i think). It feels like .h files are akin to prototyping functions. using them like this makes that clear, but thusfar i've only seen them used with classes, so it always seemed like just another piece in the magic, black box called "classes"

Comment: "miniGW" was most certainly a misspelling of [MinGW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MinGW).

Answer (score 18):

You seems to be missing some pretty basic concepts in how to build a program. I'm going to give you a very basic primer, but you *will* have to go and find more complete answers elsewhere to really understand what's going on and to get the specifics for your setup.

1. You generally tell the compiler to compile each of your cpp files. When a cpp file has an `#include` statement, that basically copies and pastes the `include`d file into your cpp file before compiling (this is done by the preprocessor). Each of these complete units (cpp file, with includes) processed by the compiler is called a *translation unit*. Each translation unit produces one *object file*.
2. Object files contain compiled code, but they are often not complete. That is, they contain references to code that are not contained in them. Basically, they can say "now call this function, I don't know where it is or what it does, but you should call it".
3. The *linker* is then used to link object files, perhaps together with libraries, into an executable (or a library). The linker's job is to "resolve" all of the references to external code in each object file by finding the relevant code in other object files and libraries.
4. Libraries come in two flavours: *shared* libraries (`.dll`s in Windows) and *static* libraries. A static library is linked into the executable (or other library) by the linker, meaning you can then use the executable without the library (relevant library code becomes part of the executable). You can also link an executable/library against a shared library, in which case you'll need a copy of that shared library every time you run your executable -- the operating system will need to dynamically link your compiled code to the shared library before running it.

So, back to your question.

You have, broadly, three choices: compile then link all of your `cpp` files directly each time in a single project; compile useful reusable code into a static library, then link your project against it; or compile useful reusable code into a shared library, link your project against it, and make sure to ship the shared library with the result so it can be run.

Most projects of any reasonable size will combine at least two of these. Multiple `cpp` files will be part of the project code, which will be compiled as separate translation units and given to the linker. Most projects will also use some libraries (either that you write yourself, or that others have written) that are linked statically or dynamically as appropriate.

Unfortunately (imho) C++ as a language doesn't come with a single build system to organise all of this for your (more recent languages often do). There are several different compilers/linkers and *many* different build systems that can all do all of this. The specific steps you need to take, unfortunately, depend an awful lot on your choice of compiler and build system.

Answer (score 8):

That is quite simple. As [JMAA said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51488008/how-can-i-call-functions-from-one-cpp-file-in-another-cpp-file/51488203#51488203), you should do some research to understand these concepts, but being practical, this is what you would do:

You'll define an **functionsExample.cpp** where you have to define all your functions and also an **functionsExample.h** where you'll declare your functions.

You'll have this as the **functionsExample.cpp**:

```
#include "functionsExample.h"
#include <iostream>
int example(int x, int y)
{
    return x + y;
}
```

Ans this as **functionsExample.h**:

```
#ifndef FUNCTIONSEXAMPLE_H
#define FUNCTIONSEXAMPLE_H

int example(int x, int y);

#endif
```

Then in the .cpp file you want to run the **example** function. Simply add:

```
#include "functionsExample.h"
```

But as I said, you should do some research about header guards, preprocessor directives and files organization to have a deeper knowledge about this. Some links I would recommend:

[Header Files](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/19-header-files/)

[Preprocessor Directives](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/110-a-first-look-at-the-preprocessor/)

Comment: It would be a better practice to `#include "functionsExample.h"` also in the functionsExample.cpp, as the first linked source advised: "This allows the compiler to catch certain kinds of errors at *compile time* instead of link time."

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is to use a build tool.  My personal preference is [Meson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meson_(software)), but [CMake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMake) is more popular.  There are others, but you can't go wrong with either of these.  Both of these are cross-platform and support different toolchains.  This means that as long as your code is standard C++ you can compile it just as easily using [MinGW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MinGW), [Visual Studio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio), [G++](https://www.cprogramming.com/g++.html), or [Clang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clang) without changing anything.  They let you choose from the available toolchains on your platform. Each has a quick start tutorial on its web site.

The configuration file, which you write, specifies what program source files to use and what executables to build.  The build chain that you use is selected in the configuration step and after that you can build your executables by running [Make](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_%28software%29) or [Ninja](https://ninja-build.org/manual.html) (required by Meson and recommended for CMake). If you change your source, you only need to rerun Make or Ninja.  Of course only the changed parts are rebuilt.  Only the executables that are affected by your changes are relinked as well.

It may be educational to watch a few verbose builds to get familiar with the build process on your system.

PS: Traditionally, in #includes you use angle brackets (<>) for system headers and quotes ("") for your own.  It has to do with where to look for them first.

Answer (score 0):

*This post is meant to be a complementary answer to existing answers that don't address a very common problem (especially among beginners): including header files with templates implemented in separate source files.*

---

> Basically I have multiple .cpp files with all my functions I made for use with binary trees, BST, linked lists, etc.

Since:

- You have tagged your question with [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), and
- C++ has templates, and
- You have container-like data structures (BST, linked list, etc.) which I assume use templates

I'd like to point out to a common problem not mentionned in the other answers. Consider the following two files:

File `class.hpp`:

```cpp
#pragma once // Non-standard but supported by almost (if not) all compilers

// Some class
template<class T> class Class {
    T data;
public:
    Class();
};

// Some function
template<class T> T square(const T& x);
```

File `class.cpp`:

```cpp
#include "class.hpp"
#include <iostream>

template<class T> Class<T>::Class()
{
    std::cout << "Class()" << '\n';
}

template<class T> T square(const T& x)
{
    return x*x;
}
```

Try and instanciate a `Class` object, or call `square()`:

```cpp
#include "class.hpp"
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    Class<int> clss; // should output Class()
    std::cout << square<int>(3); // should print 9
}
```

Compile with:

```
g++ class.cpp main.cpp -o cpptest.exe
```

```
./gcc/bin/ld.exe: main.cpp(.text+0x15): undefined reference to 'Class<int>::Class()'
./gcc/bin/ld.exe: main.cpp(.text+0x28): undefined reference to 'int square<int>(int const&)'
```

---

#### The problem

##### 1. Templates

Imagine you have this function:

```cpp
template<class T> T add(const T& x, const T& y)
{
    return x + y;
}
```

And you call it like:

```cpp
int res = add<int>(2, 3);
```

It's at the moment of the call (i.e. when the compiler sees the call to `add()`) when a copy of the function implementation is created by the compiler:

```cpp
int add(const int& x, const int& y)
{
    return x + y;
}
```

And then your call will become:

```cpp
int res = add(2, 3);
```

This obviously implies that the template function implementation must be visible to the compiler when the call is found, so the compiler will be able to make a copy of it. And for the compiler to find/see it, it must be in the same [translation unit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106149/what-is-a-translation-unit-in-c).

That's how templates magic works under the hood. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3914642/difference-between-instantiation-and-specialization-in-c-templates) for more information.

##### 2. The compiler and the linker

Going through the compilation steps:

1. Replace all the `#include` directives with the included file contents.
2. Compile every `.cpp` file (also called a "translation unit") separately. The result will be an object file for each unit. Note that some code (like in `main.cpp`) refers to another code (`class.cpp`). This will be resolved in the next step.
3. Link the translation units altogether into an executable file. (See [JMAA](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4956078/jmaa)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51488203/16835308) for more details).

Applying step 1 above, we will have two translation units (`.cpp` files):

File `class.cpp`:

```cpp
template<class T> class Class {
    T data;
public:
    Class();
};

template<class T> T square(const T& x);

/* <iostream> code ... */

template<class T> Class<T>::Class()
{
    std::cout << "Class()" << '\n';
}

template<class T> T square(const T& x)
{
    return x*x;
}
```

File `main.cpp`:

```cpp
template<class T> class Class {
    T data;
public:
    Class();
};

template<class T> T square(const T& x);

/* <iostream> code ... */

int main()
{
    Class<int> clss;
    std::cout << square<int>(3);
}
```

Applying step 2 above, we will have just addresses (this is not how real object code looks like, it's just a simplification):

File `class.cpp`:

```cpp
/* Nothing to generate for 'Class' definition. Remember, templates are just models (hence the word "template"), not concrete classes/functions. */

/* Nothing to generate for square()'s definition: It's a template, not concrete. */

iostream_object_code

/* Nothing to generate for 'Class' implementation. It's a template, not concrete. */

/* Nothing to generate for square()'s implementation: It's a template, not concrete. */
```

File `main.cpp`:

```cpp
/* Class is not concrete: nothing is generated. */

/* square() is not concrete: nothing is generated. */

iostream_object_code

int main()
{
    class_int_obj_placeholder clss;
    __operator_xx(cout_obj_ref, fn100017(3));
}
```

Apply step 3 above, and you'll get the `undefined reference` [errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10632251/undefined-reference-to-template-function): The linker doesn't know of any `fn100017()` in any translation unit. Because `square()` is a template (or a model), the compiler did not generate any concrete implementation. The same applies for `Class`.

#### The solution

1. The obvious fix is to put both the definition and the implementation in the same header file. This way, when included in `main.cpp`, both will be visible to the compiler, because they are in the same translation unit.
2. Or, if you want to keep your definitions and implementations separate, make your implementations in a header file, then include it at the end of the definition header:

File `class.hpp`:

```cpp
#pragma once

template<class T> class Class {
    T data;
public:
    Class();
};

template<class T> T square(const T& x);

#include "class_impl.hpp"
```

File `class_impl.hpp`:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

template<class T> Class<T>::Class()
{
    std::cout << "Class()" << '\n';
}

template<class T> T square(const T& x)
{
    return x*x;
}
```

Compiling and running `main.cpp` with the same command:

```
Class()
9
```