# Anybody explain the line of C++ code

Tags: c++, testcase

```
std::ostream & _return  = ::operator<<(_os, _event)
```

Especially I would like to know: What is the data type of `_return` and How can I print it in console.

Comment: Look up C++ references.

Answer (score 2):

> std::ostream & _return  = ::operator<<(_os, _event);
>
> Especially I would like to know: What is the data type of _return and How can I print it in console.

The code looks for an `operator<<` at global scope (not in any namespace), which can accept the `_os` and `_event` objects as parameters.  It's not necessarily true, but given "<<" is the normal way streaming output is done in C++, you can expect that it's probably going to be a function such as:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Event&);
```

Where Event is whatever type the `_event` object has, and I've assumed `_os` will be some type *derived from* `std::ostream`, and consequently able to be handled by a reference to `std::ostream`.

Almost all such `operator<<` functions return their first stream argument, so your code is probably doing some output, then effectively assigning to `_return` as if it were:

> std::ostream& _return  = _os;

Here, the *static* type of `_return` itself is `std::ostream&` - a reference to a `std::ostream` (Standard output stream) object, but the run-time type will be whatever type `_os` has... that's the type of object that operations on `_return` will invoke polymorphically.  This could be `ofstream`, `ostringstream` or many other types.

> How can I print it in console.

There is no Standard way to get textual type names in C++, though runtime polymorphic types do have runtime type information that includes an optional textual field that's normally populated with a type name of some sort - whether it will have full namespace qualifiers, name mangling or whatever is unspecified, but you can try it easily enough:

```
std::cout << typeid(_return).name() << '\n';
```

(For GCC, see [Unmangling the result of std::type_info::name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/281818/unmangling-the-result-of-stdtype-infoname/281876#281876) for tips on unmangling such type names)

Answer (score 0):

`_return` is just a variable of type "Reference to `std::ostream` class object".
And it is initialized with a return value of `<<` operator in global namespace `::operator<<(ostream& os, const some_Obj_reference& ref)`.

Ttis could be as well
`std::ostream & _return  = (_os <<_event);`