# How can I see the type deduced for a template type parameter?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

Is there an easy way to force compilers to show me the type deduced for a template parameter?  For example, given

```
template<typename T>
void f(T&& parameter);

const volatile int * const pInt = nullptr;
f(pInt);
```

I might want to see what type is deduced for `T` in the call to `f`. (I think it's `const volatile int *&`, but I'm not sure.) Or given

```
template<typename T>
void f(T parameter);

int numbers[] = { 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 };
f(numbers);
```

I might want to find out if my guess that `T` is deduced to be `int*` in the call to `f` is correct.

If there's a third-party library solution (e.g., from Boost), I'd be interested to know about it, but I'd also like to know if there's an easy way to force a compilation diagnostic that would include the deduced type.

Comment: you want this during compilation, or at runtime? the latter can be done with `#include <typeinfo>` and `typeid(T).name()`

Comment: `std::is_same<T, const volatile int*&>::value`?

Comment: @TemplateRex: I'd like to see the type during compilation.

Comment: @Rapptz: In general, I want to see what type the compiler has deduced, not guess what it's deduced and then see if my guess is correct.

Comment: @KnowItAllWannabe Not possible without run-time type information.

Comment: Are you looking for an error, or a warning?

Comment: @Mehrdad: I'd be willing to consider both. What I'm fundamentally looking for is a way to see the types that template type deduction comes up with.

Answer (score 20):

**Link time solution:**

On my platform (OS X), I can get the linker to give me this information by simply making a short program that is complete, minus the definition of the function I'm curious about:

```
template<typename T>
void f(T&& parameter);  // purposefully not defined

int
main()
{
    const volatile int * const pInt = nullptr;
    f(pInt);
}

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "void f<int const volatile* const&>(int const volatile* const&&&)", referenced from:
      _main in test-9ncEvm.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Admittedly I get the "triple reference", which should be interpreted as an lvalue reference (due to reference collapsing), and is a demangling bug (perhaps I can get that fixed).

---

**Run time solution:**

I keep a `type_name<T>()` function handy for this type of thing.  A completely portable one is possible, but sub-optimal for me.  Here it is:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <string>

template <typename T>
std::string
type_name()
{
    typedef typename std::remove_reference<T>::type TR;
    std::string r = typeid(TR).name();
    if (std::is_const<TR>::value)
        r += " const";
    if (std::is_volatile<TR>::value)
        r += " volatile";
    if (std::is_lvalue_reference<T>::value)
        r += "&";
    else if (std::is_rvalue_reference<T>::value)
        r += "&&";
    return r;
}
```

I can use it like:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
void f(T&& parameter)
{
    std::cout << type_name<T>() << '\n';
}

int
main()
{
    const volatile int * const pInt = nullptr;
    f(pInt);
}
```

which for me prints out:

```
PVKi const&
```

That's not terribly friendly output.  Your experience may be better.  My platform ABI is based on the [Itanium ABI](http://mentorembedded.github.io/cxx-abi/).  And this ABI includes this function:

```
namespace abi
{
    extern "C"
    char*
    __cxa_demangle(const char* mangled_name, char* buf, size_t* n, int* status);
}
```

I can use this to demangle C++ symbols into a human readable form.  An updated `type_name<T>()` to take advantage of this is:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cxxabi.h>

template <typename T>
std::string
type_name()
{
    typedef typename std::remove_reference<T>::type TR;
    std::unique_ptr<char, void(*)(void*)> own
        (
            abi::__cxa_demangle(typeid(TR).name(), nullptr, nullptr, nullptr),
            std::free
        );
    std::string r = own != nullptr ? own.get() : typeid(TR).name();
    if (std::is_const<TR>::value)
        r += " const";
    if (std::is_volatile<TR>::value)
        r += " volatile";
    if (std::is_lvalue_reference<T>::value)
        r += "&";
    else if (std::is_rvalue_reference<T>::value)
        r += "&&";
    return r;
}
```

And now the previous `main()` prints out:

```
int const volatile* const&
```

Comment: This is useful, thanks. I've also since found that similar information is available via `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` under gcc and clang and under `__FUNCSIG__` under MSVC. These produce strings, so they lead to runtime solutions.

Comment: @KnowItAllWannabe unless you use it in e.g. `static_assert`

Comment: @sehe: Alas, `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` acts like a variable, not a string literal, so it can't be used inside `static_assert`.

Comment: @HowardHinnant I believe this can be solved at compile time. I would greatly appreciate if you provided feedback on my answer. I am not an expert and maybe missed some important point or some corner cases. Many thanks!

Comment: @HowardHinnant On gcc 4.7.2 at least, if you pass `nullptr` as fourth argument to `abi::__cxa_demangle()`, it doesn't demangle the name anymore. Please consider passing a pointer to a local int variable even if you later ignore the error code. In this context, I would greatly appreciate your feedback on [my previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4541470/341970).

Answer (score 8):

I have tried the followings with g++ 4.7.2 and clang++ 3.4 (trunk 184647); they both give

**a compile-time error and the error message is containing the deduced type**.

I have no access to MSVC 12, please check what happens and provide feedback.

```
#include <string>

template <typename T>
struct deduced_type;


template<typename T>
void f(T&& ) {

    deduced_type<T>::show;
}

int main() {

    f(std::string()); // rvalue string

    std::string lvalue;

    f(lvalue);

    const volatile int * const pInt = nullptr;

    f(pInt);
}
```

The error messages: g++ 4.7.2

error: incomplete type `deduced_type<std::basic_string<char> >` used in nested name specifier
error: incomplete type `deduced_type<std::basic_string<char>&>` used in nested name specifier
error: incomplete type `deduced_type<const volatile int* const&>` used in nested name specifier

and clang++

error: implicit instantiation of undefined template `deduced_type<std::basic_string<char> >`
error: implicit instantiation of undefined template `deduced_type<std::basic_string<char> &>`
error: implicit instantiation of undefined template `deduced_type<const volatile int *const &>`

The note / info messages also contain the type of `f` with both compilers, for example

In instantiation of `void f(T&&) [with T = std::basic_string<char>]`

It's butt-ugly but works.

Comment: @HowardHinnant Thanks for checking. (I have upvoted your answer 3 hours ago.)

Answer (score 2):

To get the compiler to show you the type of a variable (perhaps in a round about way);

```
T parameter;
....
void f(int x);
...
f(parameter);
```

compiler should complain that "T" cannot be converted to int, assuming that it actually can't.

Comment: This is an interesting idea, but, at least with gcc 4.8.1 and MSVC 12, it has shortcomings. In the first example, gcc reports the type twice, once as `const volatile int * const &&&` (yes, with three ampersands!), once as `const volatile int * const`. MSVC also reports the type twice, once as `volatile const int *const`, once as `volatile const int *const &`.

Answer (score 2):

A slightly more succinct way to trigger the compiler diagnostic from [Ali's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18683145/1464861) is with a deleted function.

```
template <typename T>
void f(T&&) = delete;

int main() {
    const volatile int * const pInt = nullptr;
    f(pInt);
    return 0;
}
```

With GCC 8.1.0, you get:

`error: use of deleted function 'void f(T&&) [with T = const volatile int* const&]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/6P8zGnb1E) to easily examine the generated demangled assembly code. Use your code as an example:

```cpp
template<typename T>
void f(T&& parameter);

const volatile int * const pInt = nullptr;

int main()
{
    f(pInt);
}
```

The `call xxx` instruction will tell you the exact type deducted by the compiler.

```
main:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:pInt
        call    void f<int const volatile* const&>(int const volatile* const&)
        mov     eax, 0
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

T is deduced to the type inside `<>`, which is `int const volatile* const&`.

```
call    void f<int const volatile* const&>(int const volatile* const&)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check compiler's abstract syntax tree (AST). For example, the clang compiler's abstract syntax tree gives really detailed information about how templates are deduced.