# What does the type Ss mean?

Tags: c++, type-conversion, reinterpret-cast, delete-operator

I have read a disk file into memory into an array declared as by:

```
char * buffer = new char [length];
```

then reinterpreted the array:

```
std::string strbuf(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(buffer), length);
```

and immediately check the type of the string provided.

```
cout << "buffer is: " << typeid(buffer).name() << '\n';
cout << "strbuf is: " << typeid(strbuf).name() << '\n';
buffer is: Pc
strbuf is: Ss */
```

As you can read, the string "strbuf" is of type Ss. What does that mean?

Comment: It's a mangled typename. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/281818/unmangling-the-result-of-stdtype-infoname)

Comment: _One_ question per question, please. As should be self-evident. You wouldn't go to the Wikipedia article on "Dog" and expect to also find a description of cats.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Ss` is the mangled name for `std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>` according to the [Itanium ABI mangling rules](https://mentorembedded.github.io/cxx-abi/abi.html#mangling).

If you have trouble applying the rules in your mind, you can use the `c++filt` tool:

```
$ c++filt <<< _ZSs
std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >
```

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
std::string strbuf(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(buffer), length);
```

Which really should be:

```
std::string strbuf(buffer, length);
```

does not *interpret* `buffer` as a string. It *copies* it. `strbuf` at this point owns its own copy of the entire buffer. When you do `delete [] buffer;`, `strbuf` still has its own and is still a perfectly valid object. Since `string` manages its own memory, you don't need to explicitly delete it either - you can just let it go out of scope.

Comment: Ok - I see now why only one question in each post. Both my questions were answered but by different posters. I can only accept one post as the answer though, so one good answer does not get recognized.