# What counts as a symbol while mangling C++ names on Linux?

Tags: c++, linux, name-mangling

On Linux g++/clang++

```
void test10058l(void*(*)(void*),void*(*)(const void*),const void*(*)(void*));
```

is mangled as `_Z10test10058lPFPvS_EPFS_PKvEPFS3_S_E`

- According to g++/clang++, how many symbols are there in this function definition ?
- What are the substitutions ? (`S_`, `S0_`, `S1_`, ...)
- More specifically what is `S3_` ?

(edit - adding some context)

The [D language](http://dlang.org/) allows to [interact with C++](http://dlang.org/cpp_interface.html) by declaring symbols as `extern(C++)`.

Unfortunately the current implementation is not always correct - I'm trying to fix it by implementing the current g++/clang++ name mangling scheme [as defined by the Itanium C++ ABI](http://mentorembedded.github.io/cxx-abi/abi.html#mangling).

Since this documentation is not crystal clear, I'm having a hard time understanding what accounts as a symbol.

Comment: Why do you need to know exactly? It's depending on the actual compiler's implementation. You can use [abi::__cxa_demangle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/281818/unmangling-the-result-of-stdtype-infoname) to demangle `typeinfo::name()` results BTW.

Comment: My question was not clear, I added some context. I'll have a look at `abi::__cxa_demangle` this might help. Thx !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After several experiments I managed to understand how symbols are substituted. In particular, qualified types create new symbols and function account for symbols by themselves. A pointer to a function is then another symbol.

Here is the breakdown of the substitutions for the example I provided.

`void test10058l(void*(*)(void*),void*(*)(const void*),const void*(*)(void*));`

```
    _Z10test10058lPFPvS_EPFS_PKvEPFS3_S_E
S_                  ^^                    : Pv          void*
S0_                ^^^^^^                 : FPvS_E      void*()(void*)
S1_               ^^^^^^^                 : PFPvS_E     void*(*)(void*)
S2_                           ^^          : Kv          const void
S3_                          ^^^          : PKv         const void*
S4_                       ^^^^^^^         : FS_PKvE     void*()(const void*)
S5_                      ^^^^^^^^         : PFS_PKvE    void*(*)(const void*)
S6_                               ^^^^^^^ : FS3_S_E     const void*()(void*)
S7_                              ^^^^^^^^ : PFS3_S_E    const void*(*)(void*)
```

I started this [git repository](https://github.com/gchatelet/gcc_cpp_mangling_documentation) to report my findings regarding linux/osx GCC C++ name mangling.

Answer (score 0):

Function mangling is compiler dependent activity, there is no standard direction for that.  You can use following tool to demangle http://demangler.com/

Comment: Yes I guess my question was missing some context. Please take another look.