# Bad typeinfo name for exceptions

Tags: c++, exception, typeid, typeinfo

When I run the following program, I get a mangled typeinfo name.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <typeinfo>

namespace std
{

class really_out_of_range
    : public out_of_range
{
public:
    explicit really_out_of_range(const string& __s) : out_of_range(__s) {}
    explicit really_out_of_range(const char* __s)   : out_of_range(__s) {}

    virtual ~really_out_of_range() _NOEXCEPT {}
};

}

void test () noexcept(false)
{
    throw std::really_out_of_range("x > 20");
}

int main () noexcept(true)
{
    try {
        test();
    } catch (const std::exception& e) {
        std::cout << "Exception caught: " << typeid(e).name() << ": " << e.what() << '\n';
    } catch (...) {
        std::cout << "Unknown exception caught\n";
    }
}
```

Here is the output:

> Exception caught: St19really_out_of_range: x > 20

However, when I change the noexcept specification on the `test()` function to `true` in order to trigger a call to `std::terminate()`, I get this output:

> libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type
>   std::really_out_of_range: x > 20

I thought that std::terminate() might be able to provide the unmangled type named because it explicitly handled each standard exception type, but that's clearly not the case because it also correctly handles the new exception type that I defined above.

So, my question is why is the typeinfo name correct in `std::terminate()`, but not when I try to access it directly?  Or, more to the point, what function does `std::terminate()` call that provides an unmangled class name?

Comment: My suspicion is that `std::terminate` is just demangling the typeinfo name. There is likely an environment-internal function that it uses. For example, G++ has `abi::__cxa_demangle`.

Comment: The result of `typeid(anything).name()` is implementation defined.   `std::terminate()` is not required to demangle (or to present the type of an exception in any particular form), and there is no standard function to demangle a name. Lastly, adding declarations to namespace `std` as you have gives undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

After [cdhowie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/501250/cdhowie)'s comment, I found the answer here: [Unmangling the result of std::type_info::name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/281818/unmangling-the-result-of-stdtype-infoname)

Basically, you `#include <cxxabi.h>` and call `abi::__cxa_demangle` if you're using GNU.  But you have to be careful with the memory management.

However, you can also use boost.  Then you just `#include <boost/core/demangle.hpp>` and call `boost::core::demangle( name )`.

.