# In Qt/GCC/C++; How to create a wrapper which both captures an argument expression text, and returns/casts the argument's explicit type?

Tags: c++, qt, gcc, polymorphism, preprocessor

## Backstory (You can skip)

In trying to form the question as best I could, I was informed that the second set of parentheses for a `#define` macro is not a `return` like I thought it was, but actually a `cast`. To that, as far as I know; the only way to capture the expression text is by using the `#define` macro. The tricky part, perhaps impossible, is to capture the explicit `type`'s text, but what do I know?

Also; the reason I specified this to Qt and not just C++/gcc, is that I figure that a solution might involve a class like `QVariant` which adds some polymorphism, however this is not ideal as it is difficult to distinguish between some various basic types, like `int` vs `bool`.

## What I am hoping to achieve

Basically, I want a wrapper, I am guessing a macro, which will log the nested expression text, its value, and return its exact nested's type (no implicit conversions).

For example:

```
/* Basic Definitions */
// log() could be overloaded or use different namespaces if need be
// and have preproccessor directives choose the appropriate one,
// although I dont suspect that is possible.
QVariant log(QString expression, QVariant value, QString type); 

// TYPE is placeholder code. Normally I specify a real type like "bool"
// I am hoping TYPE can represent the captured type text
// #EXPR returns the text of the expression, in case you didnt know
#define LOG(EXPR)(TYPE)(log(#EXPR, EXPR, TYPE));
```

In this sample code:

```
/* Sample Code */
QString path;
if (LOG(path.isEmpty())) {
    path = LOG(QDir::currentPath());
}
```

The wrapper `LOG` should log the following:

```
Expression: "path.isEmpty()" Value: "True" Type: "bool"
Expression: "QDir::currentPath()" Value: "/home/akiva/Programming/" Type: "QString"
```

Id like to see if I could achieve this **without** having to resort to multiple macro namespaces, like this:

```
/* Bad solution because I dont want to have to specify LOG_bool & LOG_QString */
QString path;
if (LOG_bool(path.isEmpty())) {
    path = LOG_QString(QDir::currentPath());
}
```

and I figure one possible solution would reveal itself if I could capture the text of the type, but I am open to all solutions, be it Macros, Templates, Functions or what have you.

My minimum requirements are:

- Needs to capture the expression text. (I know how to do that with macros)
- Only require one wrapper namespace, because I dont want to accidentally use the wrong wrapper corrupting my logs or which may cause an implicit conversion, thus potentially changing the intended behaviour of the wrapped expression.
- The wrapper must return/cast the exact type of the nested expression, or in other words, not affect the exact intended behaviour of the nested expression.

Being able to actually log the type, like `Type: "bool"` & `Type: "QString"` would be nice, but is not required.

I hope this all makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to ask for [`typeid(EXPR).name()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid)? It's implementation-defined and could be mangled. Otherwise, you need some canonical transformation from the `std::type_info` object yielded by `typeid(EXPR)` to a pretty string.

Comment: Or, specifically for Qt, just call `QVariant::typeName()` on the value argument ...

Comment: @Useless I will take what I can get. The type name is nice to have for logging, but ultimately the goal is a wrapper which will wrap expressions, log them, but not prevent the expression from serving their purpose. for example `if (path.isEmpty()){}` should still function the same if I do `if (LOG(path.isEmpty())){}` as should `QString path = LOG(QDir::currentPath());`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic approach is not to use a `QVariant`, but to have a template that returns the value of the expression, of the same type:

```
#define LOG(EXPR) (log(#EXPR, EXPR))

void log(const std::string &); // logging function
std::string demangle(const char*); // demangler - see below
template <typename T> T log(const char * expr, T &&value) {
  auto const &type = std::typeid(value);
  std::ostringstream os;
  os << "expression \" << expr << "\" = (" << value << ") type: "
      << demangle(type.name());
  log(os.str());
  return std::forward(value);
}
```

The demangler can be adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4541470/1329652):

```
#ifdef __GNUG__
#include <cxxabi.h>
#include <memory>
std::string demangle(const char *name) {
  int status;
  std::unique_ptr<char, void(*)(void*)> res {
    abi::__cxa_demangle(name, NULL, NULL, &status),
    std::free
  };
  return {(status==0) ? res.get() : name};
}
#else
std::string demangle(const char *name) {
  return {name};
}
#endif
```

If you want to use Qt types, you'd use `QString` instead of `std::string`:

```
void log(const QString &); // logging function
QString demangle(QLatin1String); // demangler - see below
template <typename T> T log(QLatin1String expr, T &&value) {
  auto const type = demangle(std::typeid(value).name());
  log(QStringLiteral("expression \"%1\" = (%2) type: %3")
      .arg(expr).arg(value).arg(type));
  return std::forward(value);
}

#ifdef __GNUG__
#include <cxxabi.h>
#include <memory>
QString demangle(QLatin1String name) {
  int status;
  std::unique_ptr<char, void(*)(void*)> res {
    abi::__cxa_demangle(name.latin1(), NULL, NULL, &status),
    std::free
  };
  return {(status==0) ? QLatin1String(res.get()) : name};
}
#else
QString demangle(QLatin1String name) { return {name}; }
#endif
```

Comment: I worked around with it. I had to replace the `QLatin1Strings` with `QStrings` for it to compile. Not sure if that is a big deal... and I could not call `std::typeid`, and instead had to just do `typeid`, and `return std::forward(value);` became `return std::forward<T>(value);` -- It seems to be working swimmingly. Many thanks.