# print the name of a function's input that was given as reference

Tags: c++

say we have a function as:

```
void func(const int& A){

     print_name(A);
}
```

which I am looking for it to print:

```
name: A
```

anyone has a suggestion for how we can define "print_name" to achieve such functionality, without explicitly writing the argument's name?

Comment: You are asking for reflection, which is not yet there in C++. What is your actual issue which you are trying to solve?

Comment: [You already asked this earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69673047/65863), why are you asking it again?

Comment: You can make `print_name` being a macro: `#define print_name(name) std::cout << "name: " << #name << std::endl`. This prints `name: A`: https://godbolt.org/z/1fv5Mbb5a