# How to print full frame stack backtrace in C code， like gdb

Tags: c++, c, stack, frame, backtrace

I'm tring to use program ***to print frame stack *** in C/C++ code.

Below is a demo find form internet:

[print call stack in C or C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3899870/print-call-stack-in-c-or-c)

```
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

#include <cxxabi.h> // __cxa_demangle
#include <elfutils/libdwfl.h> // Dwfl*
#include <execinfo.h> // backtrace
#include <unistd.h> // getpid

using namespace std;

// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/281818/unmangling-the-result-of-stdtype-infoname
std::string demangle(const char* name) {
    int status = -4;
    std::unique_ptr<char, void(*)(void*)> res {
        abi::__cxa_demangle(name, NULL, NULL, &status),
        std::free
    };
    return (status==0) ? res.get() : name ;
}

std::string debug_info(Dwfl* dwfl, void* ip) {

    uintptr_t ip2 = reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(ip);
    Dwfl_Module* module = dwfl_addrmodule(dwfl, ip2);
    char const* name = dwfl_module_addrname(module, ip2);
    std::string function_name = name ? demangle(name) : "<unknown>";



    int line_num = -1;
    char const* file_name;
    if (Dwfl_Line* dwfl_line = dwfl_module_getsrc(module, ip2)) {
        Dwarf_Addr addr;
        file_name = dwfl_lineinfo(dwfl_line, &addr, &line_num, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr);
    }
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << std::setw(16)<<std::setfill('0') <<ip << ' ' << function_name;
    if (file_name)
        ss << " at " << file_name << ':' << line_num;
    ss << std::endl;
    return ss.str();
}

std::string gen_framestack_backtrace() {
    // Initialize Dwfl.
    Dwfl* dwfl = nullptr;
    {
        Dwfl_Callbacks callbacks = {};
        char* debuginfo_path = nullptr;
        callbacks.find_elf = dwfl_linux_proc_find_elf;
        callbacks.find_debuginfo = dwfl_standard_find_debuginfo;
        callbacks.debuginfo_path = &debuginfo_path;
        dwfl = dwfl_begin(&callbacks);
        assert(dwfl);
        int r;
        r = dwfl_linux_proc_report(dwfl, getpid());
        assert(!r);
        r = dwfl_report_end(dwfl, nullptr, nullptr);
        assert(!r);
        static_cast<void>(r);
    }

    // Loop over stack frames.
    std::stringstream ss;
    {
        void* stack[512];
        int stack_size = ::backtrace(stack, sizeof stack / sizeof *stack);
        for (int i = 0; i < stack_size; ++i) {
            ss << i << ": ";

            // Works.
            ss << debug_info(dwfl, stack[i]);

#if 0
            // TODO intended to do the same as above, but segfaults,
            // so possibly UB In above function that does not blow up by chance?
            void *ip = stack[i];
            std::string function;
            int line = -1;
            char const* file;
            uintptr_t ip2 = reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(ip);
            Dwfl_Module* module = dwfl_addrmodule(dwfl, ip2);
            char const* name = dwfl_module_addrname(module, ip2);
            function = name ? demangle(name) : "<unknown>";
            // TODO if I comment out this line it does not blow up anymore.
            if (Dwfl_Line* dwfl_line = dwfl_module_getsrc(module, ip2)) {
              Dwarf_Addr addr;
              file = dwfl_lineinfo(dwfl_line, &addr, &line, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr);
            }
            ss << ip << ' ' << function;
            if (file)
                ss << " at " << file << ':' << line;
            ss << std::endl;
#endif
        }
    }
    dwfl_end(dwfl);
    return ss.str();
}

void my_func_2() {
    std::cout << gen_framestack_backtrace() << std::endl;
    std::cout.flush();
}

void my_func_1(double f) {
    (void)f;
    my_func_2();
}

void my_func_1(int i) {
    (void)i;
    my_func_2();
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    long long unsigned int n;
    if (argc > 1) {
        n = strtoul(argv[1], NULL, 0);
    } else {
        n = 1;
    }
    for (long long unsigned int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        my_func_1(1);   // line 122
        my_func_1(2.0); // line 123
    }
}
```

Run:

```
$ sudo apt install libdw-dev libunwind-dev
$
$ g++ -fno-pie -ggdb3 -O0 -no-pie -o a.out -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic-errors test.cpp -ldw -lunwind -ggdb
$ ./a.out
```

Result:

```
0: 000000000x401ab1 stacktrace[abi:cxx11]() at /home/wxq/test/test7.cpp:71
1: 000000000x401c11 my_func_2() at /home/wxq/test/test7.cpp:106
2: 000000000x401ca2 my_func_1(int) at /home/wxq/test/test7.cpp:117
3: 000000000x401d01 main at /home/wxq/test/test7.cpp:128
4: 000x7f3e4ee4dbf6 __libc_start_main at ../csu/libc-start.c:310
5: 000000000x401479 _start at ../csu/libc-start.c:-1

0: 000000000x401ab1 stacktrace[abi:cxx11]() at /home/wxq/test/test7.cpp:71
1: 000000000x401c11 my_func_2() at /home/wxq/test/test7.cpp:106
2: 000000000x401c8f my_func_1(double) at /home/wxq/test/test7.cpp:112
3: 000000000x401d16 main at /home/wxq/test/test7.cpp:129
4: 000x7f3e4ee4dbf6 __libc_start_main at ../csu/libc-start.c:310
5: 000000000x401479 _start at ../csu/libc-start.c:-1
```

***But above solution can not print function arguments***

Does any one have solution to print backtrace in C/C++ program, just like gdb `bt` command?

***Just like below command***

```
#0  createObj1 (handle=0x5555559291c0, shimHandle=0x55555595a850) at /home/wxq/setup.cpp:983
#1  0x00007ffff60a3763 in initialize (this=0x55555595a850, config=...)at /home/wxq/test.cpp:197
#2  0x00007ffff60a24f2 in create_extended (setup=0x5555559291c0) at /home/wxq/test.cpp:509
#3  0x0000555555555538 in main (argc=5, argv=0x7fffffffe0e8) at /home/wxq/core_model.cpp:145
```

Comment: I don't have an answer for you but names of types of variables are not  available at run-time.  gdb extracts them from debug information (DWARF, stabs, or native format), at least -g1, and you would need -g3 for macros.  There is a libdwarf++ library.  You may also want to check out pahole.

Comment: It looks like boost stacktrace can at least include the argument type.

Comment: Are you looking for this ？ https://github.com/bombela/backward-cpp